# cordova-plugin-firebasex, Error: Unknown server client ID

Tags: cordova

Fresh clone from https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex-test.git.
I have already copy google-services.json and change SERVER_CLIENT_ID in config.js.
But I still get error Unknown server client ID
any suggest ?

Comment: What do you mean by SERVER_CLIENT_ID in config.js ?

Comment: I give value of SERVER_CLIENT_ID with OAuth Client ID from google API Credentials